Android Codec2 component store service crashes while stopping the service
I am debugging a crash issue reported in the Android Codec2 integration of an audio decoder. The decoder component starts as a lazy service. Please see the source code below,
int main()
{
     ALOGE("Lazy Service starting...");

     ::android::hardware::configureRpcThreadpool(/*threads*/ 8, /*willJoin*/ true);
     using namespace ::android::hardware::media::c2::V1_0;

    ALOGE("Instantiating Codec2's IComponentStore service...");
    android::sp<IComponentStore> store(
            new utils::ComponentStore(android::MyComponentStore::Create()));
    
    if (store == nullptr) {
        ALOGE("Cannot create Codec2's IComponentStore service.");
    }
    
    status_t status;
    {
        auto serviceRegistrar = ::android::hardware::LazyServiceRegistrar::getInstance();
        status = serviceRegistrar.registerService(store, "default3");
    }
    LOG_ALWAYS_FATAL_IF(status != android::OK, "Error while registering  default3 lazy service: %d",
            status);

    ::android::hardware::joinRpcThreadpool();
    ALOGE("Lazy Service stopped...");

    return 0;
}

The decoder service is running while playing media files through an Android application. The audio and video playback is working correctly.
But I see a crash dump in the adb log messages when the media playback stops(when I click the 'back' button to exit from the player window)
--------- beginning of crash
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_panther/panther:14/UP1A.231005.007.A1/eng.audio.20240510.161544:userdebug/test-keys'
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Revision: 'MP1.0'
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2024-06-10 23:18:42.779663327+0530
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 28s
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: /vendor/bin/hw/vendor.hardware.media.c2@1.0-audiocodec-service
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : pid: 4195, tid: 4222, name: HwBinder:4195_4  >>> /vendor/bin/hw/vendor.hardware.media.c2@1.0-audiocodec-service <<<
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : uid: 1046
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : signal 0 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'terminating'
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000107e  x2  0000000000000006  x3  00000070e6d55190
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x4  fefefefeff666d68  x5  fefefefeff666d68  x6  fefefefeff666d68  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007387a77050  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000007387ac0b60
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x12 000000738a41c020  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 00000000000547f6  x15 00000004077fedd6
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007387b2ccf8  x17 0000007387b09470  x18 00000070e6ac0000  x19 0000000000001063
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000000000107e  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 00000070e6d55300  x23 00000070e6d552c0
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x24 ffffff80ffffffc8  x25 0000007387b2ef38  x26 0000000000000364  x27 0000000000000362
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000005000  x29 00000070e6d55210
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007387ab1178  sp  00000070e6d55170  pc  0000007387ab11a4  pst 0000000000001000
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : 20 total frames
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000000000005c1a4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 19c32900d9d702c303d2b4164fbba76c)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000501b4  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libc++.so (abort_message+276) (BuildId: 0e7a8aa3d376c1c6544d64065247b1a8)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000064bf8  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler() (.__uniq.205383134706309982814331919004001075825)+72) (BuildId: 0e7a8aa3d376c1c6544d64065247b1a8)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000000650c8  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+8) (BuildId: 0e7a8aa3d376c1c6544d64065247b1a8)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 0000000000065080  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libc++.so (std::terminate()+32) (BuildId: 0e7a8aa3d376c1c6544d64065247b1a8)
06-10 23:18:42.875  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000000aa818  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::thread::~thread()+24) (BuildId: 0e7a8aa3d376c1c6544d64065247b1a8)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000029b14  /vendor/lib64/libcodec2_hidl@1.0.so (android::hardware::media::c2::V1_0::utils::InputBufferManager::~InputBufferManager()+20) (BuildId: 64cb2eacaa9e46287c6dee01e446565f)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000000cd8f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__cxa_finalize+144) (BuildId: 19c32900d9d702c303d2b4164fbba76c)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000000bfa98  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (exit+24) (BuildId: 19c32900d9d702c303d2b4164fbba76c)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0000000000074070  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::details::ClientCounterCallback::tryShutdownLocked()+320) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 0000000000073c6c  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::details::ClientCounterCallback::onClients(android::sp<android::hidl::base::V1_0::IBase> const&, bool)+300) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 000000000009a96c  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hidl::manager::V1_2::BnHwClientCallback::_hidl_onClients(android::hidl::base::V1_0::BnHwBase*, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+332) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 000000000009acf8  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hidl::manager::V1_2::BnHwClientCallback::onTransact(unsigned int, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, unsigned int, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+88) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000000ac41c  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::BHwBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, unsigned int, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+156) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 0000000000052874  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+996) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 000000000006669c  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+668) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 00000000000705f8  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24) (BuildId: 3797c42cd4e3a5ee79f1e760e1466d51)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 000000000000fe18  /apex/com.android.vndk.v34/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+584) (BuildId: 625583f4cd601a4f751800f91b840e76)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000000c9ccc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204) (BuildId: 19c32900d9d702c303d2b4164fbba76c)
06-10 23:18:42.876  1046  4195  4222 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 000000000005db00  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 19c32900d9d702c303d2b4164fbba76c)

Detailed log message is available here
The problem is occurring only when the service is running as a lazy service(dynamic service). The crash issue is not observed, if the service starts with the device startup.
Here is the service's .rc file.
service vendor-media-c2-hal-1-0-audiocodec /vendor/bin/hw/vendor.hardware.media.c2@1.0-audiocodec-service
    interface android.hardware.media.c2@1.0::IComponentStore default3
    class hal
    oneshot
    disabled
    user mediacodec
    group mediadrm camera drmrpc system
    ioprio rt 4

